# C#: Convert array to use in params with additional parameters

Tags: c#, arrays, parameters

I have a method that takes params. Inside the method another variable shall be added to the output:

```
private void ParamsTest(params object[] objs)
{
  var foo = "hello";
  // Invalid: Interpretes objs as single array parameter:
  Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}", foo, objs);
}
```

When I call

```
ParamsTest("Hi", "Ho");
```

I would like to see the output.

```
hello Hi Ho
```

What do I need to do?

I can copy `foo` and `objs` into a new array and pass that array to `WriteLine` but is there a more elegant way to force `objs` to behave as params again? Kind of `objs.ToParams()`?

Comment: Do not get sidetracked by the Console.WriteLine example or the format string. This is not my real issue. Real question: How can I make WriteLine see 4 (format, foo and 2 array elements) args instead of 3 (format, foo and array).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If your problem is just to add another element to your array, you could use a List

```
List<object> list = new List<object> { "hello" };
list.AddRange(objs);
Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}, ...", list.ToArray());
```

`params` is not a datatype. The parameters datatype is just still a plain array.

Comment: This is my current solution. So no way to do this more elegantly, i.e. without allocating a list and copying objects around?

Comment: The problem is, that you can't resize an array in .NET. So either use another collection datatype or copy values around.

Answer (score 6):

I would use [`string.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd988350.aspx) to do the formatting:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", foo, string.Join(", ", objs));
```

Comment: This solves the problem for the Console.WriteLine example, but naturally :) WriteLine is not my real problem, just a (too simple?) illustration.

Answer (score 1):

You can use foreach loop like this

```
string objsString = string.Empty;
foreach (var ob in objs)
    objsString += ", " + ob.ToString();
Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}", foo, objsString);
```

Or there is even better way:

```
string paramsString = string.Join(", ", objs);
Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", foo, paramsString );
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the `params` array

```
var foo = "hello";
Console.Write(foo);
objs.ForEach(obj => Console.Write(", {0}", obj.ToString()));
Console.WriteLine();
```

Or use [**`String.Join()`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876.aspx) to create a string representation of the array.

```
var foo = "hello";
string output = String.Join(", ", objs);
Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", foo, output);
```